# DELETE operation in SQL Server extremely slow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a DB on an SQL server 2017. A simple table with some foreign keys and cascading deletes. The structure is real simple.

The main `tblAS0002` has a clustered index with the field ID (int). Also all child tables `tblAS0002_xxx` have an foreign key field `IdAddress` refereing to the Id field in `tblAS0002`. The child tables are nearly empty for this sample: less than 20000 records, no more than 2 records per main record, mostly all main records have no associated records in the child tables.

Als child tables haven an index upon `IdAddress` (the foreignkey to the `tblAS0002.Id` field)

The main table (`tblAS0002`) has about 2.5 million records. For this test I choose a record that has no records in the child tables. When I execute now a delete of 1 record, the execution time is above 60secs.

The statement I execute is a direct `DELETE FROM tblAS0002 WHERE Id=2218801`

See execution plan below in a public link.

Looking into the execution plan, I can see only one operation taking over 1 minute, and it is a scan of the primary key index of the tblAS0002. But why?

- DBCC CHECKDB was executed.
- All indexes were recreated.
- The tblAS0002_History_Links has 0 records. (the table with the long execution time)
- The record I deleted for test purposes has no associated record in any child table! The primary Id does not occur in any other table as IdAddress (foreign key)

What happens here with the slow delete? I can't see a missing index anywhere. What can I do find the problem behind the scene?

Here the [Create Script for the tables](https://pastebin.com/hUTRY1r2) (simplified as far as possible)

[Paste of the execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1eqT9KgU)

Comment: Rather than posting a link to Dropbox (which I myself won't trust, and also is blocked by the office firewall) use [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/); then we don't have to download something from an anonymous user on the internet. As (many of us are) IT professionals, we know very well the dangers of downloads from public sharing domains, especially in work environments (where many us of use SO). Also, please do include the DDL of your (related) tables along with the indexes (and keys, as you say there are cascade deletes enabled). Thanks.

Comment: I took the plunge and downloaded your plan on my home machine. Although I highly recommend still following @Larnu suggestion and please update with a Paste The Plan link and table creation structures. I will say that this surely has something to do with foreign keys to your history table. I assume they are not on the same Id field as you are deleting from. So it looks like the query does a full scan for the foreign key/cascading delete to get the fields for the foreign key.

Comment: I added the plan. You'll need to add the structures. The issue lies in your history cascading and that address/parentid field.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Paste the Plan ( @JacobH ) . There are certainly far more tables/indexes involved than I was expecting there (at most I was expecting 4 scan/seek operations, not 18). The scan of table `tblAS0002` is certainly going to be the first "port of call", as it's scanning 2,380,354 rows, where as everything else is a seek. I completely agree that we need to see the relationship between `tblAS0002` and `tblAS0002_History_Links`. The DDL of both tables, their indexes, and their Primary/Foreign keys will help us do that.

Comment: And if you are sure the keys and indexes are solid, here's something you might want to look at: https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/foreign-key-trusted/

Comment: Create script added. tblAS0002_History_Links is empty! 0 records.

Comment: I used DBCC CHECKDB. Please tell me what else can I do to verify the structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice execution plan!!!
There are a series of cascade deletes (which in turn fire other cascade deletes).
every delete-->spool is yet another cascade deletion: the deleted rows are put into a spool/temp structure and the spool is used for finding the referencing rows from other tables.

```
eg. delete tblAS0002 -> spool[tblAS0002]
delete history{join}spool[tblAS0002] -> spool[history]
delete history_links{join}spool[history]
```

> Looking into the execution plan, I can see only one operation takeing
>   over 1 minute, and it is a scan of the primary key index of the
>   tblAS0002. But why?

this is the operation at the bottom of the plan.

There is a self-reference in  tblAS0002:  tblAS0002.IdParent --> references tblAS0002.Id

There is no index for IdParent, deleting a single Id requires a table scan of tblAS0002 in order to verify a not exists== assert:!(left semi join) , that the deleted id is not referenced by any IdParent.